# Python Tkinter Images

Tags: image, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am experimenting with the tkinter-GUI, but I have some trouble working with images.
My code looks like so:

`logo = PhotoImage(file="imagesource.gif")
 w1 = Label(root, image=logo).pack(side="right")`

However, when I try to run my code in Python 3.5.2, I get this error message:

`traceback (most recent call last):
File "~/Tkinter.py", line 4, in <module>
logo = PhotoImage(file="imagesource.gif")
File "~/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3394, in __init__
Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
File "~/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3350, in __init__self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "image source.gif"`

Does anybody know how to deal with this error?

Thanks,
Narusan

Comment: Are you absolutely 100% certain the file is a gif? Just naming it that doesn't make it so.

Comment: I have a MacBook Pro (macOS sierra), and when it asked me to change the file type or only the extension, I pressed "the file type", so yes, it should be a gif

Comment: It also says Kind: Graphics Interchange Format (GIF), so yes, i'm 100% certain

Comment: Try using `ImageTk` from `pillow` (fork of PIL) module: `from PIL import ImageTk`, `logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="imagesource.gif")`.  Also use the `file` command to check the actual image type of your image file in a terminal: `file imagesource.gif`.

Comment: If tkinter is saying it doesn't recognize the data, it's not going to lie about it. There is definitely something wrong with your data if you're getting that error.

Answer (score -1):

Below commands will work with both python2 and python 3.

First install pillow:

```
pip install pillow
```

Python code:

```py
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
icon1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('image.jpg'))
btn = Button(window, image = icon1, command = find_file)
```